# How put biographical

Tags: bibliographies

How put biographical ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\Large
 \begin{center}
title.\\ 

\hspace{10pt}

% Author names and affiliations
\small name\\

%\hspace{15pt}

\small University\\



\end{center}

\hspace{10pt}

\normalsize

Text 1% cite biographical need 


\end{document}
```

And this is my cite:

```
@article{hector1999plant,
  title={Plant diversity and productivity experiments in European grasslands},
  author={Hector, Aea and Schmid, B and Beierkuhnlein, C and Caldeira, MC and Diemer, M and Dimitrakopoulos, PG and Finn, JA and Freitas, H and Giller, PS and Good, J and others},
  journal={science},
  volume={286},
  number={5442},
  pages={1123--1127},
  year={1999},
  publisher={American Association for the Advancement of Science}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For more details, you can look [here](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/bibtex/)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@article{hector1999plant,
  title={Plant diversity and productivity experiments in European grasslands},
  author={Hector, Aea and Schmid, B and Beierkuhnlein, C and Caldeira, MC and Diemer, M and Dimitrakopoulos, PG and Finn, JA and Freitas, H and Giller, PS and Good, J and others},
  journal={science},
  volume={286},
  number={5442},
  pages={1123--1127},
  year={1999},
  publisher={American Association for the Advancement of Science}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\Large
 \begin{center}
title.\\ 

\hspace{10pt}

% Author names and affiliations
\small name\\

%\hspace{15pt}

\small University\\



\end{center}

\hspace{10pt}

\normalsize

Text 1~\cite{hector1999plant}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

[image]